# multiplying a number with a column of text file

Tags: awk

i have a text file that arranged as follows,I want to multiply 0.5 with 4th column values from rows no 2 to 4 in every block separated by > > >

```
$ cat input



> > >
-20.0000000 2.99699998 -0.00000000 -2.369154943153262138e-03
-19.8999996 2.99699998 -0.00000000 -6.730181630700826645e-04
-19.7999992 2.99699998 -0.00000000 -2.990400729080041394e-03
-19.7000008 2.99699998 -0.00000000 -1.659155823290348053e-03
-19.6000004 2.99699998 -0.00000000 -1.845874078571796374e-03
-19.8000004 4.99699998 -5.00000000 -3.845874078571796374e-03
-20.8000004 4.99699998 -5.00000000 -6.845874078571796374e-03
> > >
-20.0000000 4.99699998 -0.00000000 -2.369154943153262138e-03
-19.8999996 5.99699998 -0.00000000 -6.730181630700826645e-04
-19.7999992 9.99699998 -0.00000000 -2.990400729080041394e-03
-19.7000008 2.99699998 -0.00000000 -1.659155823290348053e-03
-19.6000004 2.99699998 -0.00000000 -1.845874078571796374e-03
> > >
-20.0000000 4.99699998 -0.00000000 -2.369154943153262138e-03
-19.8999996 2.99699998 -0.00000000 -6.730181630700826645e-04
-19.7999992 2.99699998 -0.00000000 -2.990400729080041394e-03
-19.7000008 5.99699998 -0.00000000 -1.659155823290348053e-03
-19.6000004 2.99699998 -0.00000000 -1.845874078571796374e-03
> > >
```

```
$ cat output

> > >
-20.0000000 2.99699998 -0.00000000 -2.369154943153262138e-03
-19.8999996 2.99699998 -0.00000000 -6.730181630700826645e-04*0.5
-19.7999992 2.99699998 -0.00000000 -2.990400729080041394e-03*0.5
-19.7000008 2.99699998 -0.00000000 -1.659155823290348053e-03*0.5
-19.6000004 2.99699998 -0.00000000 -1.845874078571796374e-03
-19.8000004 4.99699998 -5.00000000 -3.845874078571796374e-03
-20.8000004 4.99699998 -5.00000000 -6.845874078571796374e-03
> > >
-20.0000000 4.99699998 -0.00000000 -2.369154943153262138e-03
-19.8999996 5.99699998 -0.00000000 -6.730181630700826645e-04*0.5
-19.7999992 9.99699998 -0.00000000 -2.990400729080041394e-03*0.5
-19.7000008 2.99699998 -0.00000000 -1.659155823290348053e-03*0.5
-19.6000004 2.99699998 -0.00000000 -1.845874078571796374e-03
> > >
-20.0000000 4.99699998 -0.00000000 -2.369154943153262138e-03
-19.8999996 2.99699998 -0.00000000 -6.730181630700826645e-04*0.5
-19.7999992 2.99699998 -0.00000000 -2.990400729080041394e-03*0.5
-19.7000008 5.99699998 -0.00000000 -1.659155823290348053e-03*0.5
-19.6000004 2.99699998 -0.00000000 -1.845874078571796374e-03
> > >
```

My tried code is

```
awk '{print $4*0.5}' input > output
```

However, it multiplies 0.5 with every rows values of 4th column instead of rows no 2 to 4.Can anybody suggest me how to implement this kind of tricks using `awk`.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{if ($0~/> > >/) {line=0} else {line+=1} if (line>=2 && line<=4) {$4*=0.5} print}' input
```

1. If it's the delimiter line (`> > >`), reset line counter, otherwise increment it
2. If line counter is between 2 and 4 (inclusive), multiple field 4
3. Print the line (modified or not)

EDIT: To concatenate instead of multiply, use this:

```
awk '{if ($0~/> > >/) {line=0} else {line+=1} if (line>=2 && line<=4) {$4=$4"*0.5"} print}' input
```

EDIT again: To force exponential notation, you can use this:

```
awk '{if ($0~/> > >/) {line=0} else {line+=1} if (line>=2 && line<=4) {$4=sprintf("%.18e",$4*0.5)} print}' input
```

Comment: ok...how can the multiplied values would be of same length as given sample something like -6.730180000000000000e-05, can you please update ur answer

Comment: Oh sorry I wasn't paying attention to your sample output. I actually multiplied; you want to concatenate the string `*0.5`.

Comment: no no you are doing right thing, but instead of just -6.73018000 i need values like -6.730180000000000000e-05

Comment: i think it is format something like  "%.18e"

Comment: Do you want to say you require output to be in exponential notation? Because this was not mentioned anywhere in the question. (I did have multiplication by a million for a minute or three at start, just to see which values were affected. If that is what you saw, try to run it again.)

Comment: yes as input the output should be written in same length

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { CONVFMT="%.18e" }
/^>/ { lineNr=0 }
(2 <= lineNr) && (lineNr <= 4) {
    $4 *= 0.5
    $5 = "<- modified"
}
{
    print
    lineNr++
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk input
> > >
-20.0000000 2.99699998 -0.00000000 -2.369154943153262138e-03
-19.8999996 2.99699998 -0.00000000 -3.365090815350413322e-04 <- modified
-19.7999992 2.99699998 -0.00000000 -1.495200364540020697e-03 <- modified
-19.7000008 2.99699998 -0.00000000 -8.295779116451740265e-04 <- modified
-19.6000004 2.99699998 -0.00000000 -1.845874078571796374e-03
-19.8000004 4.99699998 -5.00000000 -3.845874078571796374e-03
-20.8000004 4.99699998 -5.00000000 -6.845874078571796374e-03
> > >
-20.0000000 4.99699998 -0.00000000 -2.369154943153262138e-03
-19.8999996 5.99699998 -0.00000000 -3.365090815350413322e-04 <- modified
-19.7999992 9.99699998 -0.00000000 -1.495200364540020697e-03 <- modified
-19.7000008 2.99699998 -0.00000000 -8.295779116451740265e-04 <- modified
-19.6000004 2.99699998 -0.00000000 -1.845874078571796374e-03
> > >
-20.0000000 4.99699998 -0.00000000 -2.369154943153262138e-03
-19.8999996 2.99699998 -0.00000000 -3.365090815350413322e-04 <- modified
-19.7999992 2.99699998 -0.00000000 -1.495200364540020697e-03 <- modified
-19.7000008 5.99699998 -0.00000000 -8.295779116451740265e-04 <- modified
-19.6000004 2.99699998 -0.00000000 -1.845874078571796374e-03
> > >
```

Obviously just delete `$5 = "<- modified"` when you're done testing.